# Error Cannot Find Symbol In Program

Tags: java, arrays, types

Im trying to create a program that adds and removes songs in a playlist but I keep getting this error of cannot find symbol if (!found) { this section code is just Delete song by shifting the following songs over it in the array I just need some help on this error and my program will be complete. Thanks!

```
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class MusicPlaylist {

    // the maximum number of songs the music playlist can hold

    public static final int MAX_SONGS = 3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create arrays and size counter
        int size = 0;
        String[] songsTitles = new String[MAX_SONGS];
        double[] songsLength = new double[MAX_SONGS];

        // Enter Songs
        while (true) {
            // check max number of songs
            if (size >= MAX_SONGS) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Max number of songs reached.");
                break;
            }
            // Get title or exit command
            String title = JOptionPane
                    .showInputDialog("Insert song #" + (size + 1) + " title (or Cancel to finish adding songs):");
            if (title == null)
                break;

            // check if there is a title
            if (title.isEmpty()) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Title must not be null.", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                continue; // start from the top

                break;
            }
            // Get length
            double length;
            try {
                length = Double
                        .parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insert song" + (size + 1) + " length is minutes: "));
                if (length <= 0)
                    throw new NumberFormatException();
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Length must not be a valid, posite double number.", "Error",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                continue; // start from the top
            }
            // Add song
            songsTitles[size] = title;
            songsLength[size++] = length;

        }

        // show list and allow to remove songs
        while (size > 0) { // if size <=0, nothing to remove
            // show list
            String list = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                list += songsTitles[i] + "  '+ songsLength[i] + 'min/n";
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, list);

            // get title or exit command
            String title = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insert title to delete(or Cancel to finish removing songs):");
            if (title == null)
                break;

            // Find and delete song or show error message
            boolean found = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                if (songsTitles[i].equals(title))
                    // Delete song by shifting following songs over it in the
                    // array
                    for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {
                        songsTitles[j - 1] = songsTitles[j];
                        songsLength[j - 1] = songsLength[j];
                    }
                size--;
                found = true;
            }
        }
         **if (!found) {**
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Song not found", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        // Show report
        String list = "*** REPORT ***/n";
        double total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            list += songsTitles[i] + "   " + songsLength[i] + "mins/n";
            total += songsLength[i];
        }
        list += "/nTotal length: " + total + " minutes.";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, list);

    }

}
```

Comment: `Javascript != java` **-_-**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring that variable `found` inside while loop and trying to access it outside of while loop,so the error is there because local variable can not be accessed outside.

*Solution* - Decalre the variable `found` before while loop like this

```
         boolean found = false;
         // show list and allow to remove songs
         while (size > 0) { // if size <=0, nothing to remove
         // show list
         ......
```

There is one more issue in this piece of code which won't compile.

```
// check if there is a title
 if (title.isEmpty()) {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Title must not be null.","Error",       JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
continue; // start from the top

break;
}
```

here you are using `continue` and `break`.`break` statement won't be reachable.so you need to remove it.Then you are good to go.

Comment: its giving me an MusicPlaylist.java:69: title is already defined in main(java.lang.String[] for this sections of code -   // get title or exit command
                 String title = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insert title to delete(or Cancel to finish removing songs):");
                 if (title == null);

Comment: Change the name of variable title to something else.there are two variables with title name.change that and you will be good.

Comment: last error MusicPlaylist.java:55: variable length might not have been initialized
for this section of code  songsLength[size++] = length;

Comment: change  ` double length;` to ` double length=0.0;`